# How to set value a date picker with a time variable? javaFX

Tags: android, javafx, datepicker, javafx-2

I am using a custom date picker (made by JFeonix which allows you to select time, identical to the one seen in android applications such as google calendar).

Similar to how you would set the value to a date picker using LocaleDate with a DateTimeFormatter, I am trying to achieve the same thing for this time picker except my code doesn't seem to work.

This is what I use to set a datePickers value:

```
String dateWord = "2016-08-17";

createConsultationController.datePicker.setValue(localDate(dateWord));

public static final LocalDate localDate (String dateString){
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter);
    return localDate;
}
```

This is what I am attempting to set the "time date picker" with, but with no luck:

```
String startTime = "11:00";

createConsultationController.startTime.setValue(localeTime(startTime));

public static final LocalDate localeTime (String timeString) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm");
        LocalDate localTime = LocalDate.parse(timeString, formatter);
        return localTime;
    }
```

First line of the stack trace says:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '11:00' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {MinuteOfHour=0, HourOfAmPm=11},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

Comment: Are you using 12-hour 'hh' instead of 24-hour 'HH' on purpose?

Comment: Nope, wasn't sure of the difference. I changed it to HH and it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Seem's I was using the wrong class and method of the time picker to set the time, thanks to abbath for the heads up on the 24hour time formatter:

```
String startTime = "11:00";

createConsultationController.startTime.setTime(localeTime(startTime));

public static final LocalTime localeTime (String timeString) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
        LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(timeString, formatter);
        return localTime;
    }
```